# "Over the Counter" and not "On the counter"

Tags: grammar

Why it is called "Over the Counter" and not "On the counter"
What is the difference.
Can you explain in detail pls.

when i check the meaning and usage for "Over" on the net, i found that over can be used to mean 
1) More than.  e.g 1. I worked there over 5 years.
2) run across.  eg.2 The fox is running over the mat.
But here for "Over the counter" comes in what category. or it is just an idiom.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Why is _what_ called Over the Counter?  Context please!

Comment: when i check the meaning and usage for "Over" on the net, i found that over can be used  to mean 1) More than.  2) run across.  e.g1. I worked there over 5 years.  eg.2 The fox is running over the mat. But here for "Over the counter" comes in what category. or it is just a idiom.

Comment: *Over the counter* was originally usage (2), from one side of the counter to the other, going above it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Over-the-counter generally refers to items sold at retail stores as opposed to warehouse, online, or protected (e.g., drugs) merchandise. [Webster's]

"Do you sell tramadol over-the-counter?"

"No. You will need a prescription, but if that doesn't work for you, then it's only a six-hour drive to Canada. Tramadol is over-the-counter there."

"On the table" is a slang term referring to exposing oneself metaphorically.
"I put all of my chips on the table with that business decision." (I risked my wealth portfolio in a single move.) Or, "I just put my heart on the table for Sarah. I hope she doesn't carve it into pieces."

Under-the-table is not related to either.

Comment: Right. In the United States, in connection with drugs and other medications, "over-the-counter" means "over the sales counter in a simple transaction conducted with a cashier and involving stock from the store's shelves, without requiring a prescription and (therefore) the involvement of a pharmacist." The contrast is with "prescription," not with "under-the-counter" (that is, illicit) drugs.

Comment: @SvenYargs - also true in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the opposite, "under the counter," means selling something illegal. Under, over. Without actually touching the counter in either case. Et voila.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the idiom *over the counter* rather than *off the shelf*? This idiom comes from the days when stores didn't stock all their items on shelves the customer could access ... you had to go to a clerk and ask for something, and he would get it and pass it to you *over the counter*, as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grocery_store#Modernisation).

Consider for example this picture of a 1922 grocery store in Detroit:

[image]

[(image from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grocery_store#/media/File:1922_Detroit_store.jpg).

Comment: Those days aren't entirely gone. When I lived in a very marginal neighborhood in Washington, D.C., in the early 1980s, the nearest pharmacy not only had all its stock located behind counters (similar to the arrangement shown here, aside from the absence of chairs and a wood stove), but bulletproof tempered-glass shields on top of the counters and a little pass-through window for receiving aspirin, condoms, gum, etc., as well as prescription drugs. Transactions took place not so much "over the counter" as "through the window."

Comment: Certainly I recall such stores (especially hardware stores) when I was a kid in the 50s and 60s.  Pretty much gone now, in most parts of the US, save for auto parts outlets and other specialized stores.